# Way to override flex property to manually set width of span in HTML

Tags: html, css

I wanted to manually set a width of a span to make a circular highlight on an element. But even when I set the width of the span, it stretches up end to end

Its parent has flex basis property

```
element.style {
    flex-basis: 14.2857%;
    max-width: 14.2857%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Child property

```
background: #006edc;
color: white;
height: 40px;
/* width: 10px; */ -> How to set the width
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 50%;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I found the only way to set an exact width for flex items was to set both a min and max width, then the flex basis would be overwritten

Comment: The flex basis of the parent has no effect on the width of the children. `width` should be more than enough on the child...but without a [mcve] we can't diagnose. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bGNBQqN

Comment: Also `flex-basis` is **not** the same as `width`.

Answer (score 2):

The `flex-basis` is a property that you should set to the child, not the parent.
Try moving `flex-basis` from the parent to the child.

Btw, to prevent your flex-element from **stretch up to the end**, you could try setting `flex-grow: 0;`, and to prevent your flex-element from **shrink down**, `flex-shrink: 0;`. Or you could use the concise [property `flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to combine all of them (make sure `display:flex;` to the parent):

```
flex: flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis;
// for example: 
flex: 0 0 14.2857%;
// will make it 14.2857% of the parent
```

All are **flex element's property**, **not flex-container's property**

Comment: ...or just `width` will work.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yea, I'm trying to guess what he wants :v.. because we happen to not have the full context yet.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly your child elements is a SPAN? If yes add to the span `display: inline-block` because span is an inline element.

```css
div {
    flex-basis: 14.2857%;
    max-width: 14.2857%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span {
    background: #006edc;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not in a flex container it isn't...which we must assume since the OP is using flex properties.

Comment: Hi, the parent is a div and the child is a span.

Comment: The div style is ```style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;"```

Comment: While the span style is ```style="flex-basis: 14.2857%; max-width: 14.2857%; overflow: hidden;"```

Comment: @Dan That's not what your question says. You might like to edit with a suitable [mcve]